# Need 2 tables to get in Entity Framework with comma seperated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 tables as below

**StudentRequests**

```
RegistrationId  Name    ClassId
--------------------------------
     1          Mitesh   1
     2          Jain     2
```

**StudentRequestTimings**

```
Table2Id  RegistrationId   Color 
----------------------------------
1          1               7.00 AM
2          1               8.00 AM
3          2               9.00 PM
4          2               10.00 PM
```

**Classes**

```
ClassId  ClassName  RegistrationId
----------------------------------
1         Class1     1
2         Class2     2
```

I want to select data from these tables in this shape:

```
Id  Name   Color              ClassName
----------------------------------------
1   Mitesh  7.00 AM,8.00 AM   Class1
2   Jain    9.00 PM,10.00 PM  Class2
```

how can I get this data from Linq or with Entity Framework?

I have tried my code as

```
 var query = from sr in db.StudentRequests
 join c in db.Classes on sr.ClassId equals c.ClassId
 where sr.RegistrationId == registrationid
 select new { sr.StudentRequestId, c.ClassName };
```

which is retrieving single data but how can I to add table2 in this query which retrieves comma separated

**Update 1**

```
 var StudentRequestquery = from sr in db.StudentRequests
 join c in db.Classes on sr.ClassId equals c.ClassId
 join srt in db.StudentRequestTimings on sr.StudentRequestId equals srt.StudentRequestId
 where sr.RegistrationId == registrationid
 select new { sr.StudentRequestId, sr.CreatedOn, sr.Location, sr.PaymentMethod, c.ClassName,srt.FromTime,srt.ToTime };


 var loOutput = StudentRequestquery.ToList().GroupBy(item => new { item.StudentRequestId })
  .Select(group => new
    {
     Id = group.Key.StudentRequestId,
     Createdon= group.Key.CreatedOn,
     Location = group.Key.Location,
     ClassName = group.FirstOrDefault().ClassName,
     PaymentMethod = group.FirstOrDefault().PaymentMethod,
     FromTime = group.Select(item => item.FromTime).Aggregate((result, next) => result + "," + next),
     ToTime = group.Select(item => item.ToTime).Aggregate((result, next) => result + "," + next)
     });
```

Here I am getting error on  Createdon= group.Key.CreatedOn and Location = group.Key.Location

Createdon= group.Key.CreatedOn(Createdon is date) Error as 
[image]

Location = group.Key.Location(Loction is text) Error as 
[image]

Comment: @Riv I have updated my question properly, Please review

Comment: Could you explain in words what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @octavioccl all things are define in my question very clear.
Wht detail u needed

Comment: You are changing your question to be more data now that previously.  It is going to be hard for people to answer a moving target.

Comment: @djangojazz No I am not changing my question, I am just giving my updates for what I had tried from the answer what pinback has given me. Also I cannot but all my column fields in question as it contains 50 of columns so i had just define only some of the columns to get a look into it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful.
First make a join with your 3 tables and then use `GroupBy`.
You can't use LINQ to Entities in the second statement (`ToList`) is important.

```
var query = from sr in loContext.StudentRequests
            join c in loContext.Classes on sr.ClassId equals c.ClassId
            join t in loContext.StudentRequestTimings on sr.RegistrationId equals t.RegistrationId
            select new { sr.RegistrationId, c.ClassId, sr.Name, c.ClassName, t.Color };

var loOutput = query.ToList().GroupBy(item => new { item.RegistrationId, item.ClassId })
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Id = group.Key.RegistrationId,
        ClassId = group.Key.ClassId,
        ClassName = group.FirstOrDefault().ClassName,
        Name = group.FirstOrDefault().Name,
        Color = group.Select(item => item.Color).Aggregate((result, next) => result + "," + next)
    });

foreach (var loItem in loOutput)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{loItem.Id}, {loItem.Name}, {loItem.Color}, {loItem.ClassName}");
}
```

Comment: I received error on location and created on. please review my updates

Comment: You have to decide the criteria you want to group by first. I think it is not only `StudentRequestId` (like in your update). In my example is it `RegistrationId`and `ClassId`: `item => new { item.RegistrationId, item.ClassId }`. This are the only values you can select in this manner `group.Key.RegistrationId`.